# how to read a data and return it structured in a list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass the data in to create one list, im learning react and in the future i will have to prepare structures like this but reading from a JSON from the server. This working in a weird mod:

```
return (
    <div className="aui-subnavbar-element-container">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>{(ItemData)}</li>
                <Dropdown />
                <li className="dropdown-closed"><a href="#">Aplicaciones</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

var Mainlistdata = React.createClass({

    render: function() {

        var ItemData = [
            {title: 'Inicio', url: '#'},
            {title: 'Ventas', url: '#'},
            {title: 'Gastos', url: '#'},
            {title: 'Invitar a mis amigos', url: '#'}
        ];

    return (
        <div className="aui-subnavbar-element-container">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>{(ItemData)}</li>
                    <Dropdown />
                    <li className="dropdown-closed"><a href="#">Aplicaciones</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        );
    }

});

module.exports = Mainlistdata;
```

I want to get the data like this:

```
    <div className="aui-subnavbar-element-container">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href={url}>{title}</a></li>
                <Dropdown />
                <li className="dropdown-closed"><a href="#">Aplicaciones</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
<li>{(ItemData)}</li>
```

You should do something like this:

```
<ul>
  {ItemData.map(function (item) {
    return <li><a href={item.url}>{item.title}</a></li>;
  })}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works fine. If i need a submenu how can i use the data to the sub menu?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean, but you should probably pass the data to the submenu as a prop, something like `<SubMenu data={ItemData} />`. Then the item data is available in `this.props.data` inside that component.